# How to fix ri documentation duplication in rvm

Tags: ruby, jruby, rvm, ri

Here's what I want to do

```
ri Array
```

Simple, right?

Wrong!

```
More than one class or module matched your request. You can refine
your search by asking for information on one of:

    Array, TSortArray, Array, TSortArray
```

I am using RVM on Ubuntu Natty, default (and only ruby) is jruby 1.6.3

I have modified my .rvmrc to make ri documentation by default, thus

```
export rvm_gem_options=""
```

Beyond that, all is standard as far as I remember.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Limit RI to search only the documentation from Ruby's standard library

```
ri --system Array
```

or,

add this to your `.profile`

```
export RI="--system"
```

But, then you don't get to see documentation for new gems...

So, I tried not limiting RI...

Just,

```
gem rdoc --all
```

Which seemed to work.

---

But my final answer is,

Update `.gemrc` to look a little like this

```
install:  --remote --gen-rdoc --run-tests
update: --remote --gen-rdoc --run-tests
rdoc:  --all --inline-source --line-numbers --promiscuous --show-hash
```

and `.rvmrc`

```
export rvm_gem_options=""
```